# Asignar roles en una intranet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Buen día, actualmente estoy desarrollando una intranet con distintas herramientas, estoy usando devise y cancan para asignar roles a los usuarios, sin embargo tengo un problema el cual consiste en que un mismo usuario tendrá un rol diferente en cada herramienta de la intranet por lo cual podrá hacer o ver distintas cosas, me leí varios tutoriales y busque diversas gemas pero no encuentro alguna que me permita manejar esa versatilidad con un mismo login de usuario.

Si alguno conoce una forma de lograr esto o si de plano no se pueda agradecería me ayudaran a saberlo, seguiré buscando.

De antemano les agradezco.

> Editado:

Cree la siguiente estructura:

```
class CreateUserDetails < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
def change
  create_table :user_details do |t|
    t.integer :user_id
    t.integer :app_role_id
    t.integer :role_id
    t.integer :company_id
    t.timestamps
  end
end
end

class CreateAppRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :app_roles do |t|
      t.string :nombre

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :roles do |t|
      t.string :nombre

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Sin embargo no consigo que current_user logre sacar el role y la app que usará desde UserDetails que hace referencia a la tabla User de Devise.

De igual forma intente crear un modelo devise por app pero no encuentro como hacer que funcione con un solo login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te cuento la manera en que yo uso CanCan y Devise y lo adaptes a la manera que necesites

Tengo los modelos User, Rol y RolUser

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, through: :roles_users
end

class RolUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :rol
end

class Rol < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :roles_users
end
```

En `Roles` tengo registros como `id: 1, nombre: 'admin'; id: 2, nombre: 'editor', id: 3, nombre: 'read_only'; etc`

`RolesUsers` relaciona un usuario con varios roles

Y luego tengo mi clase `Ability` de la siguiente manera

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    user.roles.each do |rol|
    self.send(rol.to_sym) # llama al método de igual nombre que el rol
  end

  def admin
    can :manage, :all
  end

  def editor
    can :edit, HerramientaUno
    can :update, HerramientaUno
    # otros permisos
  end
end
```

O sea que cada rol (admin, editor, etc) tiene los permisos definidos dentro de un método con el nombre de ese rol. Cuando se inicializa `Ability`, se recuperan desde la base de datos los roles de ese user, y por cada rol se llama al método que genera los permisos. El nombre del rol debe coincidir con el nombre del método.
Y también debes agregar `load_and_authorize_resource` en los controladores para que CanCan revise si el user tiene permisos o no para ejecutar la acción.

Comment: Esa idea me gusta, solo tengo una duda, en la vista como puedes verificar el rol que juega el usuario para personalizarla?

Comment: Con esta estructura cada user tiene uno o más roles. Si vos necesitás que un user tenga en un momento un solo rol activo, tienes que agregar en el modelo `RolUser` un atributo `activo?` y poder definir de alguna forma cual de todos sus roles es el que se encuentra activo en ese momento. Y luego desde `Ability` o desde cualquier parte de la aplicación puedes saber su rol activo haciendo `user.rol_activo`. Tienes que agregar el método rol_activo tu mismo en `User`.